# Executing complex task for python script using bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

I launch python script in bash:

```
python /dumpgenerator.py --index=http://*website* --xml --curonly --images --path=/*website*
```

In order to perform many tasks  the script has to be launched in new windows with different parameters, I mean *website*

Can I launch at the same time python script which will "catch" parameters using bash commands from text file which contains *website* links? It's important that sessions have to be launched in new console windows (for every session there will be own bash and python processes)
There's also a problem to convert *website link* into applicable filesystem format when setting --path=/*website*. What regular expression should I use?

Example: the script is developed by https://code.google.com/p/wikiteam/. It doesn't let you to launch more than one wikis to archive them simultaneously. If you want more wikis to be archived, you have to copy paste (just change one parameter *website*) command in a new bash session.
It seems rather boring to open new terminal window and bash session 50 times. That's why I'm concerned how can I simplify this task.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Sounds very confusing to me..

Comment: Looks like a good use case for [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. I'm not quite familiar with it, so can't provide detailed answer, but you might want to examine the dcumentation.

Comment: **alkid**, I have edited description and added an example

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I just set up TMUX by [this](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/) article and ran copies of python /dumpgenerator.py